# AddressSanitizer: negative-size-param: (size=-2)

Tags: c++, address-sanitizer

The real code is very big with multithreading, but if to simplify it, I have the next sanitizer output and code sample:

```
==8808==ERROR: AddressSanitizer: negative-size-param: (size=-2)
    #0 0x55f43c1eedf0 in memmove (/home/bin/my_app+0x4ddf0)
    #1 0x7f8a76af1b70 in std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::_M_replace(unsigned long, unsigned long, char const*, unsigned long) (/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6+0x11eb70)
    #2 0x7f8a32036d6b in std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::assign(char const*) /usr/include/c++/6/bits/basic_string.h:1269
    #3 0x7f8a32036d6b in std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::operator=(char const*) /usr/include/c++/6/bits/basic_string.h:605
    #4 0x7f8a32036d6b in my_class::my_func(const char* str)
    ...
```

```
class my_class {
public:
void my_func(const char* str) {
 str_ = str;
}
std::string str_;
}
```

And... I just can't imagine a way how to reproduce it with simple example.

If `str == nullptr` OR any random value like `str == 0x7ff01749d1b6`, `AddressSanitizer` will report `SEGV on unknown address 0x000000000000(OR 0x7ff01749d1b6)`

If `str` points to a freed heap memory, `AddressSanitizer` will report `heap-use-after-free` error.

If `str` is a string without `\0`, `AddressSanitizer` will report `heap-buffer-overflow` error.

Can any one suggest how to reproduce `negative-size-param` error with `std::string` and `const char*`? I hope this undestanding helps me to find mistake in my real code...

Comment: No [mcve] = no way for us to help. Try adding a breakpoint on ASAN failure (not sure how), then debug from there.

Comment: Did you read the question? I am asking for minimal reproducible example for `negative-size-param`

Comment: Was gonna say. I think that was somewhat the point. He's trying to produce a [mcve] for his *own* debugging purpose using the (apparent) same conditions his code is under, and is struggling to do so. (on that note, add trying it with unterminated data to your list of failures; produces global-buffer-overflow, somewhat as expected).

Comment: @hdnn Apparently I didn't read all of it, sorry. But my advice still stands.

Comment: That call stack seems pretty suspicious. Is there a chance the target string is corrupted ? I'd start hitting those template functions in those headers at those lines and see what gives (I'm using clang on macOS, so not much help, sry). The `replace` suggests filling a previously occupied string buffer, as opposed to a new, empty one, where I would expect an alloc instead barring short-string optimization.

Comment: @WhozCraig, I think that `replace` called because all incoming strings have only two chars and `replace` is part of SSO logic... And after your words I tried to corrupt memory of destination string, but no success)

Comment: There is a lot of examples of the such error. Just Google "AddressSanitizer negative-size-param in memmove". The most often reason: erasing container elements while looping (using an invalid iterator). Your my_class object is probably in a container.